# One-Shot Git Ignore for Binary Development

Tags: git, binary, ignore

I'm going on break for the holidays and was hoping to code a solution for my senior capstone project in the form of a script. In my project, we inherited binary files from a previous team that we have to use in our development. Also, it this particular scenario we have to use git.

The software we use has a pesky edit lock functionality, and the files are binaries. We have a remove edit lock script, but when using it git recognizes that every single file has changed. So, after running the edit lock script and making our changes - git recognizes that every single file in the project hierarchy (550+) has changed.

I have to use git, and was curious if anyone had an ability to do a "one-shot" ignore such that the "git status" command would only show the differences from post edit lock to post implementation.

Research suggests it's impossible, but we'd be especially eager to hear any git based solution.

---

TLDR
We would like to:

1. Run our remove edit lock script
2. ignore all the file changes at this point
3. make our edits
4. perform a git commit while only selecting from changes that had occurred from step 3

Is this possible in git?

Comment: It seems like the checked-in version of (at least some) of your files are locked. Is this true, and if so, why?

Comment: This software adds an edit lock to any file opened by the implementer for the duration it is open - and it should delete it when done. Every now and then it seems as though this understanding of it doesn't ring true all the time, and for some members of the team it has a propensity to crash. When it does this it almost seems to lock the edit lock.

Comment: Try this: Close the software on your machine, and run the script to remove edit locks. Does git think there's anything to commit? If so, you have locked files checked in to your repository. Does that make sense? Let us know what you find.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The result seems to add to the perplexity.I ran the edit lock and committed all files. Then, I ran the edit lock again to see what was happening.     Again, all the files were registered as having changed. We ran the file in beyond compare. We can't tell the differences between the files as it's binary, but there is consistently one change near the edge of the file's contents. My best guess is there are time stamps on the files and they are also changed when removing the edit lock.

Comment: Yes, as you seem to now be thinking, this indicates to me that your unlock script is perhaps modifying files in a minor way even when they are already unlocked.

Comment: This could be difficult to debug since you're going to be comparing binary files. A good hex editor should help. I'm not sure if there are any good hex diff tools out there.